# Using a String to change a Bitmap

Tags: java, android

I have the following problem:

```
    String explosion_type = this.prefs.getString("explosion_type", "ring_explosion");

    BitmapFactory.Options optionsExplosion = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    optionsExplosion.inPurgeable = true;
    this._explosionSprite = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(_context.getResources(), 
com.forwardapps.liveitems.R.drawable.explosion, optionsExplosion);
```

I'm trying to use a String in place of the resource name, that way I can hotswap resources in the preference menu. This method causes the app to crash.

What is the proper way of implementing a situation like this? (Without making it too complicated or using if statements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use method getIdentifier on Resources object to fetch id of a drawable:

```
String explosion_type = this.prefs.getString("explosion_type", "ring_explosion");
    Log.i("imagename", explosion_type);
    BitmapFactory.Options optionsExplosion = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    optionsExplosion.inPurgeable = true;

     int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(explosion_type, "drawable", getPackageName());

        this._explosionSprite = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(_context.getResources(), imageResource, optionsExplosion);
```

Comment: your application package, replace by "yourpackage"

Comment: like this?

  int imageResource = _context.getResources().getIdentifier(explosion_type, null, _context.getPackageName());
     this._explosionSprite = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(_context.getResources(), imageResource, optionsExplosion);

Comment: No it's giving me an error:
02-11 11:31:47.584: W/ResourceType(18417): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000

Comment: is there any resource exists which have name you are storing into preference and fetching from preference

Comment: Yeah I've checked the resource files, they exist. It's when the bitmap gets used it crashes. It was working before which is strange.

Comment: can you print explosion_type value, it should not have extension

Comment: It outputs 0. I used Log.w("1", Integer.toString(imageResource)); to output it.

Comment: add a log to print explosion_value

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, I've always used Log.W(String, String) ??

Comment: see log at edited code and see second line, read what value it prints

Comment: 02-11 12:01:48.854: W/dalvikvm(20416): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aac8578)

Comment: If I type the resource manually it works, it's a problem in getting the right resource.

Comment: I've fixed it, it was missing the type of resource.

int resID = this._context.getResources().getIdentifier(explosion_type , "drawable", this._context.getPackageName());

Comment: Thanks very much, very good method. I didn't know you could do it like this. :-)